# c++ "fatal error: too many errors emitted" Build Failed

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a simple max pairwise product function in C++ to get my feet wet with this language.

The intent is to pass a vector to the maxPairwise function, sort the entire vector, then multiply together the last two integers.  The function should return an integer.  In my IDE (eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0)) in the Main function,  it shows that “ vector vect{8,3,3,7}” has an error, and when I try to compile, it says there are 20 errors, shown below. What is the problem?

```
My Code:

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int maxPairwise(const vector<int> &x){
    sort(x.begin(),x.end());

    int a = x.end()[-2];
    int b = x.end()[-3];

    return a * b;

int main() {
    vector<int> vect {8,3,3,7};
    int ans = maxPairwise(vect);
    cout<<ans<<endl;

    return 0;
}

The Error:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:632:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const int'
    swap(pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:4590:1: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_move_assignable<const int>::value' was not satisfied [with _Tp = const int]
    swap(_Tp& __x, _Tp& __y) _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_move_constructible<_Tp>::value &&
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:270:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '_Tp [_Np]' against 'const int'
    swap(_Tp (&__a)[_Np], _Tp (&__b)[_Np]) _NOEXCEPT_(__is_nothrow_swappable<_Tp>::value)
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:632:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const int'
    swap(pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:163:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__tuple_leaf<_Ip, type-parameter-0-1, >' against 'const int'
    void swap(__tuple_leaf<_Ip, _Hp, _Ep>& __x, __tuple_leaf<_Ip, _Hp, _Ep>& __y)
         ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:944:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'tuple<type-parameter-0-0...>' against 'const int'
    swap(tuple<_Tp...>& __t, tuple<_Tp...>& __u)
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2310:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__compressed_pair<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const int'
    void swap(__compressed_pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, __compressed_pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
         ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2958:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'const int'
    swap(unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x, unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __y) _NOEXCEPT {__x.swap(__y);}
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4945:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'shared_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const int'
    swap(shared_ptr<_Tp>& __x, shared_ptr<_Tp>& __y) _NOEXCEPT
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:5244:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'const int'
    swap(weak_ptr<_Tp>& __x, weak_ptr<_Tp>& __y) _NOEXCEPT
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:2472:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against 'const int'
    swap(function<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>& __x, function<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>& __y) _NOEXCEPT
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [src/Play2.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

    06:49:26 Build Failed. 20 errors, 0 warnings. (took 926ms)
'''
```

Comment: If you want your function to be able to mutate your `vector` (which sorting qualifies as), don't pass it as `const`. Also, add a closing brace to your `maxPairwise` function.